# Block coordinate descent convergence rate

Tags: convex-optimization, limits-and-convergence, nonlinear-optimization

I have read some literature about the convergence rate of block coordinate descent. They all assume that the object function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, is there any results for the convergence rate if $f$ is continuous and convex but not have Lipschitz gradient?

Update: Assume the function $f$ is smooth and block coordinate descent can find the minimum of $f$ successfully without getting stuck at some points.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent#Limitations) has a counterexample: A continuous convex function for which coordinate descent fails to converge but getting stuck in a non-optimal point.

Here are the level lines of this function:

[image: Nonsmooth coordinate descent.svg]
By [Nicoguaro](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Nicoguaro) - Own work, [CC BY 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=46261625)

Comment: I have updated the question. Assume that BCD can find the minimum of $f$, is there any known convergence rate for the problem?

Comment: For some reason I have the feeling that this question is going to change as soon as there appears  a new answer...